# Redirect one domain to another

Tags: redirect

How can I make all requests to pages at `http://a.com` go to the same page but on `http://b.com`?

htaccess currently looks like this...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. Are you using apache or nginx? What have you tried...

Comment: There are lots of plugin to update url. With the help of those plugin you can change url from all pages in just one click. For example: If your url is like this `http://a.com/page1`. Then you need to replace only `http://a.com` part (not page name), then replace only this part with the help of any update url plugin. And you can also again change it back any time. You can do this without plugin also by using update query for `wp_posts` table in phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using apache and have access to edit code files, add the following into your .htaccess file in the root directory of your site, somewhere right after the "RewriteEngine On" line.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^a.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://b.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: I've added some text to the question. Do I need an additional rule for the domain with www prefixed?

Comment: Yes, you can copy and paste the two lines for any other redirections, but there is also an "[OR]" keyword that can be used to match multiple RewriteCond's to the same RewriteRule.

Comment: Cool, it works.